# WPF Menu displays to the left of the window

Tags: wpf, xaml, menu

I have a simple Menu in a DockPanel.  Here is the XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<DockPanel>
    <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <MenuItem Name="file" Header="_File">
            <MenuItem Name="exitMenuItem" Header="E_xit"/>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
    <Grid>
    </Grid>
</DockPanel>
```

Why does the Menu drop down to the left instead of the right of the window border like most applications?

[image: screenshot of Window]

Comment: Your code does not display the MenuItem to the left as you have in the screnshot; this is on XP

Comment: Interesting.  I'll try it in my Win XP VM.  I'm using Win 7 x64.

Comment: You are right.  XP doesn't produce the same results.  Sigh.

Comment: This happens to me on EVERY WPF application (including VS 2010) on W7 x64.

Comment: Check out this [Windows](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/786-menus-open-left-right-side.html) fix to see if it helps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears that you have a tablet input device.  Follow the instructions in this link to change the handedness in your Tablet PC Settings:

- [menus appear to the left of my cursor](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7desktop/thread/4287cf85-42fe-4b49-92c6-bac01f007a6d)

Comment: I bet that is it.  I have a touch screen attached.  I'll check it out on Monday.  Thanks.

Comment: That was the problem!  What's odd is a right-handed configuration is the default and it sends all the menus to the left.  I suppose that is because on a tablet-pc the right hand would be covering up the menu.  Still it is very annoying when your machine is a laptop and the menus appear to the left even when the external touchscreen isn't connected.  Oh well.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Url is now invalid

Answer (score 2):

A fix that worked for me was:

```
        var ifLeft = SystemParameters.MenuDropAlignment;
        if (ifLeft)
        {
            // change to false
            var t = typeof(SystemParameters);
            var field = t.GetField("_menuDropAlignment", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
            field.SetValue(null, false);
            ifLeft = SystemParameters.MenuDropAlignment;
        }
```

Credit: 
https://www.telerik.com/forums/popup-is-opening-to-outside-window-in-splitbutton

Comment: Cool. +1 for the link.