# How to bring DockPanel Menu dropdowns inside the window?

Tags: c#, wpf

Just starting off learning how to use C# and WPF and I ran into a problem involving my DockPanel menu... whenever it drops down, it appears outside of the window itself, when I want it on the inside.

Here is a picture to show what I mean, the right is how I want it to work and the left is how it is currently behaving. Thanks!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rlNv.png

```
    <DockPanel>
        <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <MenuItem Header="_File">
                <MenuItem Header="_Open"/>
                <MenuItem Header="_Close"/>
                <MenuItem Header="_Save"/>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="_Help">
                <MenuItem Header="_Credits"/>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
        <StackPanel></StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>
```

Comment: Share your xaml code.

Comment: @Coder Added it to the main post, thanks

Comment: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630954/wpf-menu-displays-to-the-left-of-the-window